# marklogic, howto create range on document properties

Tags: node.js, marklogic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prop:properties xmlns:prop="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property">
  <publicationDate type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">2015-03-30</publicationDate>
  <identifier type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">2629</identifier>
  <posix type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">nobs</posix>
</prop:properties>
```

I have a document with these properties above.
I want to filter by "PublicationDate" ...
I tried with "Fields" & "Field Range Indexes" and "Element Range Indexes", but I do not find the syntax (XML or JSON) to designate this property ?

is anyone know this syntax?

kind regards

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers that give examples, please keep in mind that the element **publicationDate** is **NOT** in the namespace *http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property* in your example..  So your index configuration should have the namespace for the json/basic as defined per element and references to it as an xs:QName should not refer to "prop:"..

Trying to figure out if your index is correct? You can always try `cts:values()` from the query console and verify that your index is exactly where you expect it before using it in code.

Comment: i tried this way too, field on /v1properties/v2:publicationDate with v1 and v2 in path namesspaces, and range index on this field  everything seems fine, but select with GT date or LT date return nothing  this index looks empty

Comment: My point above is to make sure that you have the index on the correct elements with the correct namespaces.  Then verify this via the query console to ensure that what you want *really is indexed*

Comment: yes, sorry if I have not been clear, everything is good for me, the "field" and the "field index" and "query range" on the "field" ... I have not closed the issue because there may be competitive solutions ... and I do not know the process :-)))

Answer (score 1):

After many trials, this is what seems to work fine (MarkLogic 8.0-3) :

Without "Field" (where `wm` is http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic ):

```
qb.propertiesFragment(qb.value(qb.element(wm,'publicationDate'),'2015-03-30'))
```

is ok, but the following produces the same error (No  element range index ...)

```
qb.propertiesFragment(qb.range(qb.element(wm,'publicationDate'), '>=' ,'2015-03-01'))
```

With "Field"
(`wm:publicationDate`, with `wm` in Path namespaces, WITHOUT `/vm:properties/` before ...) the following seem to work fine :-)))

- `qb.propertiesFragment(qb.value(qb.field("properties_publicationDate"),'2015-03-30'))`
- `qb.propertiesFragment(qb.range(qb.field("properties_publicationDate"), '>=' ,'2015-03-01'))`

Comment: If you were able to successfully add that element to a field, then you should have all the information necessary to create a range index on it. Consider creating a new question about to the missing index.

Comment: yes, sorry if I have not been clear, everything is good for me, the "field" and the "field index" and "query range" on the "field" ... I have not closed the issue because there may be competitive solutions ... and I do not know the process :-)))

Comment: That is quite a roundabout solution, and it really shouldn't be necessary. Much simpler would be using the single range index, but if this is good enough, then I'm glad you at least found a suitable solution.

Comment: thank you;-) the solution with "element Range index" also works with the same syntax in wm: PublicationDate. This is the one I finally used in production. It is this original syntax I was missing, I had tried from the root in / prop: properties with no results ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `cts:properties-query`:

```
cts:properties-query(
  cts:element-range-query(
    xs:QName("my:publicationDate"),">",
    current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("P1D"))))
```

This example assumes a range index on `prop:publicationDate`, and also note that this assumes MarkLogic 7 or earlier. In MarkLogic 8, the name of this query appears to have changed to `cts:properties-fragment-query`.

In node.js, using the query builder, you could achieve something similar:

```
db.documents.query(
   qb.where(
     qb.fragmentScope('properties'),
     qb.propertiesFragment(
       qb.range('publicationDate', '>', ... )
     )
   )
)
```

Comment: yes, but it is for a node.js development, with query of the form (with the "Fields" for this one) : qb.value(qb.field("properties_publicationDate"), "2015-03-30") ... or qb.range(qb.field("properties_publicationDate"), '>=', "2015-03-30")

Comment: I tried this method, but it gives me the error:          `{ [Error: query documents: response with invalid 400 status]
  message: 'query documents: response with invalid 400 status',
  statusCode: 400,
  body:
   { errorResponse:
      { statusCode: 400,
        status: 'Bad Request',
        messageCode: 'XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND',
        message: 'XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:json-property-reference("publicationDate", ()) -- No  element range index for publicationDate http://marklogic.com/collation/' } } }`
hence my question to create a "range index" ...

Comment: Something similar to qb.properties(qb.value("publicationDate", "2015-03-30")) -- see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_92125 for a discussion of the properties() locator -- should work. By the way, a field or range query requires configuration through the Admin UI to define a field or range query.

Comment: yes for configuration by admin, is this method, and especially the associated syntax, I'm looking for, knowing that I created fields on values of xml content "almost easily" ;-)

Comment: @mbport I don't think fields are strictly necessary for what you're doing. First try a range index on publicationDate (and verify the configuration is correct using the method described by David Ennis), and query those values using either the example in my answer or the one from ehennum's comment.

Comment: in 8.0-3, I think "documentFragment" is a mistake, it is "propertiersFragment", which has the same function as "fragmentScope('properties')"

Comment: @mbport You're right. Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected now.